# what size should we specify for action bar width and height

Tags: android, android-actionbar, photoshop-cs5

I want to create an image in photoshope for actionbar image background, so I have to create new image but I just don't know how to specify its height and width, so that it will be fit in actionbar

any suggestion please

Comment: i would recommended you to fix sizes for all resolution devices by fixing values in values folder

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar's width vary from every devices, the suggested height of the actionbar is 56dp according to Google Design.

For more detail: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing

Wish it could help.